# Kendo Wizard Component Customization

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Right now Kendo Wizard only allows to move 1 step up or down. Do we have any way to make it all steps clickable. If I am on step 1 I can click on step 4 to see the content or click anyway to go to any step instead of only 1 +-

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/wizard/ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is stepper.linear what you are looking for?

```
stepper: {
    linear: false
},
```

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/wizard/configuration/stepper.linear